# Is there a place where you can buy single pieces of LEGO-compatible systems?

Tags: shopping, 3rd-party

I've acquired a set of MegaBloks and was amazed at the slopes with studs on top.
Unfortunately the set is $15 and there's only 6 pieces I need.

So I wanted to ask, are there any sites like Bricklink that sell MegaBloks?
(Note: I'm talking about dozens of a single piece. No mixed bags, no used sets)

Comment: I was under the impression that BrickLink could be used for clone brands too, but I was wrong: [LEGO Products Only](http://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=103&viewType=). And it goes on explicitely to: _Other brand products such as MegaBloks are not allowed on this site_

Answer (score 2):

Market places for MegaBlocks include:

- [The Bloks Forum](http://bloks.hyperboards.com/)
- eBay

Comment: I didn't realize there's a forum for that, I'll try that. But I fear I won't be able to get several dozens of one piece this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answerable with a yes or no, so I'm going to have to say no.

The main reasons something like this doesn't really exist are likely as follows:

- As with some sets in LEGO, the prices for (say, Halo) are subjective and diasagreed upon.
- MegaBloks is fairly new, compared to LEGO, which is why you also don't see a pick-a-brick for KREO, Nanoblocks, etc.
- Additional, "loose" bricks aren't manfufacured specifically for this purpose.
- Perhaps most importantly, the range of set-specific pieces is far larger than a lot of other manufacturers, thus each piece's cost is based on which set it's from.

But will we see MB pick-a-brick in the future? Probably; stay tuned.